# Linux tool that lets the media keys control web media sites

Tags: linux, gratis, ubuntu, music, hardware

What tool could I use to get the media keys on my keyboard (pause, skip, etc.) to control web media services like YouTube and Rdio. At the moment they only work with local apps like rhythm box.

It should

- Be free
- Work on Ubuntu

Comment: Problem is youtubes respond to key presses is dodgy, as the right element needs to have focus.
(I was considering a Autohotkey to map the media Play to k etc)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Chrome(ium), you can try [Streamkeys](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/streamkeys/ekpipjofdicppbepocohdlgenahaneen/related?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog).